# Como obter um trecho de uma string?

Tags: c#, .net, string

Tenho uma *string* como essa: `~/Areas/Teste/Views/home/index.cshtml`
Preciso apenas da palavra que vem logo após `~/Areas/`, no caso `Teste` (lembrando que essa palavra poderá variar de tamanho). Como faço?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Você precisa achar onde está a primeira barra e mandar fazer a procura pela segunda começando de onde está a primeira. O .NET tem o método [`Indexof()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-6.0#System_String_IndexOf_System_String_System_Int32_) para localizar um texto específico em outro. Ficaria assim:

```
var inicioPalavra = texto.IndexOf('/', texto.IndexOf('/') + 1);
```

O segundo parâmetro fornece a posição de onde deve começar a busca.

Aí você precisa descobrir a terceira barra para saber onde pegar:

```
var palavra = texto.Substring(inicioPalavra + 1, texto.IndexOf('/', inicioPalavra + 1) - inicioPalavra - 1);
```

Tem uma outra forma com [`Split()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-6.0#overloads) que parece mais simples e mais flexível e pode ser mais útil em alguns casos (mas também pode ser um desperdício em outros):

```
var palavras = texto.Split('/');
var palavra = palavras[2]; //está pegando a terceira palavra do texto separado por barras
```

Agora é fácil adaptar para outros casos semelhantes.

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/nPH2Rj). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/seBRA5). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/SplitPath.cs).

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda, os dois jeitos funcionaram muito bem :D

Answer (score 8):

(Apesar da [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/35401/8113) do Maniero estar bastante boa, e sempre interessante adicionar outras possibilidades.)

Uma solução alternativa seria utilizar expressões regulares para capturar o texto que precisa:

```
const string source = "~/Areas/Teste/Views/home/index.cshtml";
Regex regex = new Regex("^~/Areas/(?<output>[a-zA-Z0-9]+)/*/.*$");
GroupCollection capturas = regex.Match(source).Groups;
Console.WriteLine(capturas["output"]);
```

(Resultado no [.NETFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/nEKPkB))

Neste caso a expressão regular `"^~/Areas/(?<output>[a-zA-Z0-9]+)/*/.*"` vai capturar todas as letras e números que se encontrem entre o segundo e o terceiro parêntesis e coloca-los num grupo chamado `output`. A utilização do carácter `+` garante que existe pelo menos um carácter entre essas duas barras.

(Breve [introdução](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/hs600312%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) sobre expressões regulares).

Comment: É porque eu odeio Regex :P

Comment: E normal :P quando usa regex para resolver um problema, fica com dois. Mas continuo a achar que uma introdução leve ao regex faz bem.

Comment: Obrigado, é sempre importante conhecer outras formas de se resolver :D