# Recuperar parte de uma string (split ou indexOf)

Tags: c#

Tenho uma estrutura de pasta assim:

```
bco_img/3/foto_produto/
bco_img/3/foto_produto/tb/
bco_img/4/foto_produto/
bco_img/4/foto_produto/tb/
etc...
```

Quero recuperar a pasta /3/ depois /4/ e também o nome das fotos que estão dentro de cada pasta, ex: pasta: /3/  foto: xyz.jpg
Fiz algo assim:

```
string url_Fonte = Server.MapPath("BCO_IMG");

DirectoryInfo diretorio = new DirectoryInfo(url_Fonte);
   FileInfo[] Arquivos = diretorio.GetFiles("*.jpg", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
      foreach (FileInfo fileinfo in Arquivos)
      {
       string nome_dir =  fileinfo.DirectoryName;
       string v1 = nome_dir.IndexOf(@"BCO_IMG\").ToString();
    // aqui qual é o melhor? fazer uma função para recuperar pelo indexOF ou criar um Array com Split() ?

      string nome_foto = fileinfo.Name;
      }
```

Comment: É isto que quer? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/35400/como-obter-um-trecho-de-uma-string/35401#35401

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui com o *link* do Maniero

```
 string nome_dir =  fileinfo.DirectoryName;
string[] Valores = nome_dir.ToString().Split(new char[] { '\\' });
var palavra = Valores[7];
```

acho que com expressão regular também daria

```
Regex regex = new Regex("^~/BCO_IMG/(?<output>[Z0-9]+)/*/.*$");
GroupCollection capturas = regex.Match(source).Groups;
Response.Write(capturas["output"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Pelo jeito, o formato "`url_Fonte`/`sua pasta`/`etc.`/`nomearquivo`" é fixo. Então..

```
string subdir = nome_dir.ToLower().Replace(url_Fonte.ToLower() + "/", "").Split('/')[0];
// ou 
string subdir = nome_dir.Split('/')[1];
```

Depois, você pode envolver o `subdir` dentros das barras (`"/" + subdir + "/"`).

Para obter o nome do arquivo:

```
string nomearquivo = nome_dir.Split('/').ToList().Last();
// ou
string sub = nome_dir.Split('/');
string nomearquivo = sub.IndeOf(sub.Length - 1);
```

Comment: não funcionou, porém o link do bigwon, levou a uma url que da uma solução parecida com a sua que acabou dando certo. Agradeço